# How do you replace a Mercurial subrepo with a folder?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, mercurial-subrepos

I am working with a Mercurial repository that has the following structure:

```
  -- Root
     -- .hgsub
     -- SubDir
        -- SubSubDir
        -- SubRepo
```

The .hgsub file declares SubRepo as follows:

```
    SubDir/SubRepo = ssh://server//subcomponent
```

I needed to get rid of the subrepo and replace it with an actual folder in the repo called SubRepo, so I did what the [hg documentation](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository) said, removing the .hgsub file and committing. Then I put my own stuff in SubRepo and committed it, leaving me with:

```
  -- Root
     -- SubDir
        -- SubSubDir
        -- SubRepo
```

Dandy. But when I try to, say, pull changes from a repository that still has its .hgsub file, I run into trouble.

Is there a better way to replace a subrepository? Or is there something clever I should do to make this work better, like using an option to pull or temporarily changing my .hgsub to point to a new folder rather than removing it altogether?

Comment: Read carefully part "2.1. Start" about trivial relative paths and **use subrepo** with relative path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done it right.  Once you pull from the repos that still have `.hgsub` you'll need to merge your head (that doesn't have `.hgsub`) with theirs (that does), and when you remove the file as part of that merge/commit you'll end up with only one head that has no `.hgsub` and all will be right in the world.  As long as you don't 'hg update' to their remote head that still has `.hgsub` you should be fine.

Comment: Aha! This answer gave me the confidence to bang on it some more. Turns out that the issues I was experiencing were side-effects of using fetch (and probably using it in tortoise). If I do a straightforward pull and merge I don't have the same problems. Thanks! =)

Comment: No prob.  Personally, I avoid fetch entirely.  Pulling, updating, and merging are entirely, logically distinct actions in a DVCS and conflating the three leads to pain, misunderstandings, and crappy commit messages on your merges. :)